# Firebase Analytics not working when IPA is compiled

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

Whenever we are running using a simulator, or a device that is connected to XCode, we can see that the events are firing up.

But whenever we compile it to an IPA and check if the events are working, nothing is showing up.

I've already checked the package contents of the generated .app file and I saw that it is indeed using the bundle ID that I use for the app being run in the simulator.

What could be the problem? It only happens when we compile the app.

Comment: We need more context. Is the IPA targeting debug or release env? How do you check "if the events are working" through that IPA?

Comment: It has the same environment with the ones that we used when we are running using a simulator which is debug.

Comment: @Glenn I check if the events are working through the DebugView of Firebase Analytics

Comment: I think Leemur has the right answer, Jamie.

Comment: Thank you, Glenn. However, is this only applied for iOS? Because on our Android counterpart, thay can see the events even though the app is already compiled as an APK.

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer:*

**Data is uploaded when:**

- Data is >1 hour old
- Conversion event triggered
- App goes to the background

==================================================================================

*Explanation:*

In order to save user's device battery, in **Production Mode** Google Analytics for Firebase only sends data down if one of the following cases occur:

- You got data that's been sitting around for more than an hour
- The user triggers a conversion event (payment)
- Your app goes into the background

Only in **Debug Mode** the events are sent down nearly right away to the Firebase Console.

Comment: Thank you, Leemur. However, is this only applied for iOS? Because on our Android counterpart, thay can see the events even though the app is already compiled as an APK.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how is the behavior in Android environment. :P The info about iOS comes directly from Firebase Documentation. You can check this official Firebase Article: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html